# Sybase: Compare Table Data Before and After Index Recreation

Tags: sql, sybase

We need to drop and recreate indexes for specific tables in Sybase as part of performance tuning. To ensure this operation does not impact the table data, we would like to check if the table data stays the same after the index recreation. Are there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: How could recreation of an index impact table data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index creation does not change data within the tables.

A Clustered index will change the physical location of the data within the data device, but does not change the data.

A Non-Clustered index will not impact the data in any way.

If you are concerned about changes to data, then you could always perform row counts, some aggregate functions (max, min, avg, sum,etc) or do random sampling of data before and after.

Answer (score 0):

We use reorg rebuild rather than recreating indexes, which is simpler.  There is a small drawback though in that it doesn't always block other accessors, rather they fail with specific message numbers, and that can be annoying (so it's best to reorg when things are "quiet".)